# Is there a way to see what conditional compilation symbols were set during runtime?

Tags: .net

Is there a way to see what conditional compilation symbols were set during runtime or is this information lost at compile time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than side effects they may have, no, there's nothing in the metadata for it.  They only have an affect at compile time.  Easy enough to make it have such a side effect, you could wrap a dummy class with it and then at runtime use Reflection to see if it's there.

```
#if TRACE
    public static class TraceWasEnabled {}
#endif
```